# How to make infobox appear for marker with Google Maps For Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails

I want to raise a click event on a marker so that the infobox will appear.

I am able to successfully do it with this:

```
$(marker.getServiceObject().content).click()
```

This however doesn't work on mobile. Not sure why.

I tried with a mousedown event, but this doesn't work either:

```
if $('html.no-touch').length
  $(m.getServiceObject().content).click()
else
  $(m.getServiceObject().content).mousedown()
```

I was thinking there was a more elegant solution of making the infobox appear.

If anyone has any suggestions, I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must proceed this way:

```
 google.maps.event.trigger(m.getServiceObject(), 'click');
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work on mobile...neither Safari mobile nor Chrome mobile.

Comment: Weird because the sidebar example here: http://apneadiving.github.io/ works on my iphone